# Remove highly correlated variables from multi correlated data

Tags: r, correlation, r-caret

I have a very large data frame with more than 200 variables.
I am running a `cor()` to have a matrix with the correlation values and then I use the function [`caret::findCorrelation`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/caret/html/findCorrelation.html), calling `findCorrelation(x, cutoff = 0.8)` to find the highly correlated variables. After, I want to remove the variables that are highly correlated from my data one by one until I have no more highly correlated variables.

Because some variables are highly correlated with more than 40 other variables, I did run a feature importance analysis (using `Boruta()`, package [`Boruta`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Boruta)) to determine the importance of these variables and base on the importance I started removing one variable at a time (started with the lowest mean importance variable (lowest `meanImp`).

This is the process I tried to code - the first iteration is with the variable with the lowest `meanImp`, check if that variable is highly correlated (`abs(correlation indices) >= 0.8`), if so remove from the data if not keep, then I update the correlation matrix by running `cor()` and then go for the next variable with the second lowest `meanImp`, so I did that until no more highly correlated variable is found in the matrix/data.

This is the code I used:

```
remove_highly_correlated <- function(data, confirmed_sorted, cutoff = 0.80) {
  removed_vars <- character(0)
  
  while (TRUE) {
    removed_this_iteration <- FALSE  
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(confirmed_sorted)) {
      var <- as.character(confirmed_sorted$variables[i])
      
      if (var %in% colnames(data)) {
        cor_matrix <- cor(data)  
        hc <- findCorrelation(cor_matrix, cutoff = cutoff)
        
        if (length(hc) > 0 && var %in% rownames(cor_matrix)[hc]) {
          message(paste("Variable", var, "is highly correlated, removing..."))
          removed_vars <- c(removed_vars, var)  
          data <- data[, -which(colnames(data) == var)]  
          removed_this_iteration <- TRUE  
          break 
        }
      }
    }
    
    if (!removed_this_iteration) {
      break  
    }
  }
  
  return(list(data = data, removed_vars = removed_vars))
}

result <- remove_highly_correlated(data5, confirmed_sorted)

data5_filtered <- as.data.frame(result$data)
removed_variables <- as.data.frame(result$removed_vars)

cor_d5 = round(cor(data5_filtered), 4)
hc = findCorrelation(cor_d5, cutoff = 0.80, verbose = TRUE)
```

where `confirmed_sort` is the data with the mean importance and `data5` is my main data (I provided some short version of the data below).

This code worked somehow because after the code is done I tested if my final data still have highly correlated variables and I still have 6 variables that are in the `confirmed_sort` data.

The data provided below is just an example and it will not produce remaining highly correlated variables in the data.

```
blue <- c(0.57, 0.76, 0.78, 0.53, 0.26, 0.27, 0.32, 0.20, 0.63, 0.68, 0.69, 0.69, 0.35, 0.51, 0.39, 0.57, 0.67, 0.63, 0.66, 0.61, 0.54, 0.51, 0.56, 0.59, 0.52, 0.40, 0.39, 0.46, 0.82, 0.84, 0.83, 0.52, 0.59, 0.70, 0.61, 0.83)
red <- c(0.14, 0.11, 0.15, 0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.16, 0.07, 0.07, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10, 0.27, 0.19, 0.23, 0.19, 0.10, 0.11, 0.09, 0.10, 0.17, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.24, 1.00, 0.88, 0.64, 0.11, 0.12, 0.14, 0.56, 0.54, 0.36, 0.53, 0.13)
purple <- c(0.80, 0.84, 0.79, 0.76, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.59, 0.90, 0.84, 0.83, 0.86, 0.64, 0.73, 0.68, 0.73, 0.85, 0.83, 0.86, 0.85, 0.76, 0.69, 0.69, 0.71, 0.68, 0.00, 0.09, 0.28, 0.84, 0.83, 0.80, 0.35, 0.36, 0.55, 0.38, 0.81)
pink <- c(0.67, 0.73, 0.66, 0.62, 0.63, 0.63, 0.64, 0.49, 0.84, 0.74, 0.73, 0.78, 0.51, 0.58, 0.52, 0.59, 0.74, 0.72, 0.77, 0.75, 0.64, 0.54, 0.55, 0.57, 0.54, 0.00, 0.06, 0.18, 0.74, 0.73, 0.68, 0.25, 0.24, 0.41, 0.26, 0.69)
orange <- c(0.14, 0.11, 0.15, 0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.16, 0.07, 0.07, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10, 0.27, 0.19, 0.23, 0.19, 0.10, 0.11, 0.09, 0.10, 0.17, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.24, 1.00, 0.88, 0.64, 0.11, 0.12, 0.14, 0.56, 0.54, 0.36, 0.53, 0.13)
yellow <- c(0.20, 0.16, 0.21, 0.24, 0.25, 0.24, 0.23, 0.41, 0.10, 0.16, 0.17, 0.14, 0.36, 0.27, 0.32, 0.27, 0.15, 0.17, 0.14, 0.15, 0.24, 0.31, 0.31, 0.29, 0.32, 1.00, 0.91, 0.72, 0.16, 0.17, 0.20, 0.65, 0.64, 0.45, 0.62, 0.19)

data5 <- data.frame(blue, red, purple, pink, orange, yellow)

variables <- c("yellow", "purple", "blue", "green", "pink", "orange", "red")
meanImp <- c(10.07, 9.40, 9.31, 7.51, 7.49, 6.82, 6.65)

confirmed_sorted<- data.frame(variables, meanImp)
```

If I am not missing anything in the function code, any ideas why I still have highly correlated variables in my data. Any other method used to remove highly variables from a data is also welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Works for me. You're left with blue and orange.

Comment: Once you remove a variable, you need to rerun the model to determine the importance. ie assume you have 4 variable and 1,3 are correlated by .9 and 2, 4 correlated by .8 and 1,2 correlated by .6 Note that if we remove 2, the importance of 1 might increase above that of 3. Previously the features 1 and 2 captured some hidden variation in the response. But since 2 was removed, its now only var 1. Due to this, you have to run the model each time you remove a variable to determine the importance before you remove another variable

Comment: @Onyambu That's not how I understand `findCorrelation`, its output value are the indices of the variables to be removed, right? One call to `findCorrelation should be enough.

Comment: @RuiBarradas `findCorrelation` just gives you the variables that are highly correlated. I am convinced that OP is interested in reducing `multicolinearity` in their model. OP is taking into account two mechanisms, variable importance and correlation. Notice that with boruta, dropping a variable directly affects the importance of the remaining variables. Mostly even affects the importance of the variables that were highly correlated with it. So if there were 3 highly correlated variables, and almost all of them were not that important, dropping two might lead to the remaining one being (contin)

Comment: important than previously calculated. Thereby once you remove one variable, you will have to again determine the variable importance of the remaining variables

Comment: @Onyambu OK, but then `Boruta` would have to be called again to determine the variable importance of the remaining variables, not just `findCorrelation`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yeah. Thats why i stated *Once you remove a variable, you need to rerun the model to determine the importance.* The code given is just partial.

Comment: @RuiBarradas and Onyambu thanks for your help. The code did work but the final data is missing some variables considering the number of the variables were removed. For instance, when I run the function using the srx data - srx has initially 9 variables, 1 is removed (removed_vars) and 4 variables remain in the data after removal the high correlated variables. However if only one is removed, the final data should have 8 not 4. Any idea why that is happening? thank you.

Comment: @RaquelFeltrin Yes, the result is right. The missing variables are `Rejected` as irrelevant features by Boruta. Run function `remove_highly_correlated` with `verbose=TRUE` and see it printed.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I was wondering if that is what it was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the function into simpler functions. Each of them does one thing only.
Like it is said in the discussion in comments to the question, first `Boruta` is called to determine the variable importance of the variables still in the data set. Then the highly correlated ones are found and the one with least mean importance removed. This repeats until o variable is removed.

The tests are run with data sets taken from the examples in `help("Boruta")`.

```r
library(caret)
library(Boruta)

# X - regressors, can be a data.frame
# Y - response, a 1-dim vector
runBoruta <- function(X, Y, verbose = FALSE, ...) {
  vars <- names(X)
  Brt <- Boruta(X, Y, ...)
  if(verbose) {
    message("Running 'Boruta' algorithm")
    print(Brt)
  }
  i_meanImp <- nrow(Brt$ImpHistory)
  meanImp <- Brt$ImpHistory[i_meanImp, vars]
  meanImp <- meanImp[is.finite(meanImp)] |> sort()
  meanImp |>
    as.data.frame() |> 
    cbind(variables = names(meanImp))
}
remove_one_var <- function(X, confirmed_sorted, cutoff = 0.80) {
  cor_matrix <- cor(X)
  hc <- findCorrelation(cor_matrix, cutoff = cutoff)
  if (length(hc) > 0) {
    i <- confirmed_sorted$meanImp[hc] |> which.min()
    v <- confirmed_sorted$variables[ hc[i] ]
    message(paste("Variable", v, "is highly correlated, removing..."))
    X <- X[, -hc[i] ]  
  } else v <- character(0L)
  return(list(data = X, removed = v))
}
remove_highly_correlated <- function(data, resp, cutoff, verbose = FALSE) {
  work <- data[names(data) != resp]
  Y <- data[[resp]]
  rmvd <- character(0L)
  repeat {
    confirmed_sorted <- runBoruta(work, Y, pValue = 0.05, verbose = verbose)
    work <- work[confirmed_sorted$variables]
    result <- remove_one_var(work, confirmed_sorted, cutoff)
    if(length(result$removed) == 0) break
    work <- result$data
    rmvd <- c(rmvd, result$removed)
  }
  list(data = result$data, removed_vars = rmvd)
}
```

---

## Tests

These are the tests I ran.

### 1st test

In the first test with data set `srx`,

- `Boruta` discards 3 features as not important, `N1, N2, N3`;
- Then `findCorrelation` gets one highly correlated feature to remove, `nA`:
- and then the function iterates until no features are deemed important.

```r
data(srx, package = "Boruta")
srx[] <- lapply(srx, as.integer)
cutoff <- 0.8

set.seed(2024)
result1 <- remove_highly_correlated(srx, "Y", cutoff = cutoff, verbose = TRUE)
#> Running 'Boruta' algorithm
#> Boruta performed 18 iterations in 0.282912 secs.
#>  5 attributes confirmed important: A, AnB, AoB, B, nA;
#>  3 attributes confirmed unimportant: N1, N2, N3;
#> Variable nA is highly correlated, removing...
#> Running 'Boruta' algorithm
#> Boruta performed 7 iterations in 0.0775032 secs.
#>  4 attributes confirmed important: A, AnB, AoB, B;
#>  No attributes deemed unimportant.
```

---

### 2nd test

```r
iris.extended <- data.frame(iris, apply(iris[,-5], 2L, sample))
names(iris.extended)[6:9] <- paste("Nonsense", 1:4, sep = "")

set.seed(2024)
result2 <- remove_highly_correlated(iris.extended, "Species", cutoff = cutoff)
#> Variable Petal.Length is highly correlated, removing...
#> Variable Petal.Width is highly correlated, removing...

result2$data |> head()
#>   Nonsense2 Sepal.Width Sepal.Length
#> 1       3.1         3.5          5.1
#> 2       4.1         3.0          4.9
#> 3       3.8         3.2          4.7
#> 4       3.0         3.1          4.6
#> 5       3.1         3.6          5.0
#> 6       2.9         3.9          5.4
result2$removed_vars
#> [1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-21 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>